# MSAccess update statement with string containing special characters and spaces

Tags: python, sql, ms-access, pypyodbc

I am trying to update rows in a column in MS Access using Python. The string I want to update is a Windows file path which contains special characters and spaces like:

```
C:\Users\Manish\Desktop\Personal\greencindiaphotos25-10-2016\8.2.Patna_west_00001-14335_W\PA11379.jpg
```

However, when I run the sql query to update, it throws this error:

> pypyodbc.ProgrammingError: (u'42000', u"[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'C:\Users\Manish\Desktop\Personal\greencindiaphotos25-10-2016\8.2.Patna_west_00001-14335_W\PA11379.jpg'.")

It's a simple update query like:

```
UPDATE Vaishali SET Images={file_path} WHERE ID=112312;
```

How to update string like this in access?

Answer (score 0):

You should be using a *parameterized query*, e.g.

```python
file_path = r"C:\Users\Manish\Desktop\Personal\greencindiaphotos25-10-2016\8.2.Patna_west_00001-14335_W\PA11379.jpg"
id = 112312
sql = "UPDATE Vaishali SET Images=? WHERE ID=?"
params = (file_path, id)
crsr.execute(sql, params)
```